# Why is the word "pockets" used when referring to certain sections of places in a large area?

Tags: word-usage, terminology

Recently, I was reading about something related to geography. And then, I came across the word "pockets" which actually refer to some small areas in a larger area.

But can anyone tell me, why is the word "pockets" used when referring to certain sections of places in a large area.

Comment: This is a metaphor— because a _pocket_ conjures up an image of _something small._

Comment: Also, in your question tell us what you found when you looked in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The etymology of *pocket* is of a bag or pouch.

> English word pocket comes from Proto-Germanic *puk-, Proto-Indo-European *bʰew-, and later Proto-Germanic *pukô (Bag; pouch.)
>
> [Etymologeek](https://etymologeek.com/eng/pocket)

This gives us the concept of an identifiable volume that may be separate (Scottish “poke”, as of a bag of sweets) or attached (trouser pocket). Hence, one of the contemporary definitions relevant to your question:

> Pocket =
>
> a group, area, or mass of something that is separate and different from what surrounds it:
>
> ”Among the staff there are some pockets of resistance to the planned changes” (= some small groups of them are opposed).
>
> ”The pilot said that we were going to encounter a pocket of turbulence (= an area of violently moving air).”
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pocket)

Comment: Frost-free pockets often exist in an area that freezes periodically in winter, as an example. Many micro-climates exist.